# How to use "best ever"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Consider this sentences:

> This is the best ever song that I've heard.
>
> This is the best song ever that I've heard.

Which of them is correct? How should we combine "best ever" and a noun in general. I searched on the internet and only found "best song ever" combination.

Comment: Moved comments to a sort of answer - perhaps someone else can add the grammatical answer

Answer (score 1):

As a native BrE speaker I wouldn't use either of those. I would say:

> 'This is the **best** song I've **ever** heard'

I'm not sure if the two examples you have are grammatically incorrect, as such (I could see those sentences constructed like that - or at least understand what was meant). They just don't seem very idiomatic to me as a BrE speaker.

> 'This is the best [x] ever!'

Without the 'that I've heard' the second one would be very idiomatic to say in conversation.

> best ever [x]

I (personally) wouldn't use this type of phrasing - at least not in speech.

> 'This [x] is the best ever'

I would phrase it like this (or just 'This is the best ever' if it's understood what *this* is),

(Again as a native BrE speaker - I'm unsure about other jurisdictions)